# fields from multiple tables in the lookup ax 2009

Tags: axapta, x++

Can anyone tell me how to include fields from multiple tables at run time in the lookup ?

this would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

A custom lookup form has to be used, you can find the instructions here: http://www.axaptapedia.com/index.php?title=Lookup_Form